# WPF: DockPanel.Dock = "Bottom" doesn't work as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml, dockpanel

This concerns WPF.

As a simple test, I have a grid with 3 columns, the third column containing a Dock panel. In turn, this Dockpanel contains a TextBlock and a StatusBar, with the StatusBar having the (attached) attribute Dockpanel.Dock = "Bottom".

So I would expect the StatusBar to be at the bottom of the 3rd column, with the TextBlock - the one that says "I am TextBlock 3" - on top of it (within the same column).

To my surprise, however, the StatusBar appears on the RIGHT side of the TextBlock!

This is the relevant xaml-code (there is no code-behind made by me):

```
<Window x:Class="Testing.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testing"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="500" Width="1000">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="180" MaxWidth="540"  />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">I am Textblock 1</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">I am Textblock 2</TextBlock>

        <DockPanel Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock>I am Textblock 3</TextBlock>
            <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">I am the statusbar</StatusBar>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update your `DockPanel` to have `LastChildFill="False"`

```
  <DockPanel Grid.Column="2" LastChildFill="false">
```

The property is true by default, and since the `StatusBar` is the `LastChild` of the `DockPanel`, you see the behavior you are experiencing.

**LastChildFill** info from docs:

> true if the last child element stretches to fill the remaining space;
> otherwise false. The default value is true.

Comment: You have a mistake in the first sentence - LastChildFil**e**

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better solution would have been to put the status bar first and then let the text box, as the last child, fill the area above it. The relevant code would appear as follows.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="180" MaxWidth="540"  />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">I am Textblock 1</TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">I am Textblock 2</TextBlock>

    <DockPanel Grid.Column="2">
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">I am the statusbar</StatusBar>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">I am an incredibly long Textblock 3 and will fill the entire area above the statusbar...</TextBlock>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Then it will end up looking like this.

[image]